# Calling ResetBindings on bindingsource to update ComboBox results in initialising control, how to update items without initialising?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a List of strings, which is the DataSource for a BindingSource object, which in it turn is the DataSource for a ComboBox.

When I change the List (add or remove strings), I call the ResetBindings() method on the BindingSource. This updates the items in the ComboBox as expected, but it also sets the SelectedIndex to '0', instead of the uninitialised value '-1'. I want to update the items without initialising the ComboBox

I've already tried to Handle this in the SelectedIndexChanged eventhandler as follows:

```
private void cmbSelectxx_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;

   if (!cmb.Focused)
   {
      cmb.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(cmbSelectxx_SelectedIndexChanged);
      cmb.SelectedIndex = -1;
      cmb.ResetText();
      cmb.SelectedText = "";
      cmb.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cmbSelectxx_SelectedIndexChanged);
      return;
   }

   //...
}
```

but this doesn't solve my problem

Binding control to data code:

```
bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = SomeList;
cmbSelectxx.DataSource = bs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform the Add/Remove operations directly on the `BindingSource` instead of `SomeList`.  These Add/Remove operations propagate back to `SomeList`.
'
Note that if the currently selected item in ComboBox is deleted, it will update to the most appropriate value.

Assume your `SomeList` contains the values "a", "b", "c", "d".

1. If "b" is selected and it removed from the `BindingSource`, the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` will change to "c".
2. If "b" is selected and "a" is removed from the `BindingSource`, the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` will not change.
3. If "d" is selected and then removed, the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` will change to "c".